# How to print pdf file (3 inch) in bluetooth printer in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, printing, flutter-test

Print pdf file through Bluetooth printer.
How can I print a pdf file using Bluetooth 3 inch printer using flutter programming,
I tried pdf and Blue tooth printing separate but I don't know how to mix this.

Comment: I want to print other language in bluetooth printing how can i print this

Comment: But using this I Cannot print other languages. only English, but I Want to print other language so that I want to print pdf using bluetooth printer

Comment: Ok I will try. If you know the Arabic language please comment me. Tanks for the help